# Parse text from database table as HTML in final rendered PHP page

Tags: php, html, database, html-parsing

One of the fields in our PHP page is a description - occasionally there are website links included. However, when pulling this data from the database table the links remain non-clickable. How can I parse text from database table as HTML in final rendered PHP page? Thanks!

Comment: do you put the addresses in the `href=""` atttribute. could you post some of your code?

Comment: It is not code as such - it is simply text input from a form which may sometimes include a website address such as http://stackoverflow.com - but I would like that text to be rendered as a URL when pulled from the table into the PHP page. The table type is currently varchar(1500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<?php
    echo "<a href='$linkLocation'>$linkName</a>";
?>
```

[Edit]

Server-side you could transform the orginal text ($det[9]) like this (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139140/replace-non-html-links-with-a-tags) SO question):

```
<div id="text"><?php 
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/http:\/\/([,\%\w.\-_\/\?\=\+\&\~\#\$]+)/',
    create_function(
        '$matches',
        'return \'<a href="http://\'.  $matches[1] .\'">\'.  $matches[1] .\'</a>\';'
    ),
    $det[9]
);
?></div>
```

[Edit: merged the original code from your comment]
[Edit: fixed typo]

Comment: Hmmm, not really. It is not code as such - it is simply text input from a form which may sometimes include a website address such as stackoverflow.com - but I would like that text to be rendered as a URL when pulled from the table into the PHP page. The table type is currently varchar(1500)

Comment: Ah, well then you have to decide on what you define what has to be converted to url and what hasn't. `http://www.google.com`? Sure. "www.stackoverflow.com"? Probably. Stackoverflow.com? Bit.ly? someword.anotherword? It's tricky! After having decided, a regexp-string-replace, at either server or client side, should do.

Comment: A full standard URL as `http://www.google.com` is the only text to convert to a clickable URL. Hmmm, a regexp-string-replace, at either server or client side? You're going to need to talk me through that - sorry!

Comment: OK, so here is the code for pulling the database table text to the page... can you show me where to insert your code (sorry to need to be spoon fed this!):  `<div id="text"><?php echo $det[9];?></div>`

Comment: Unfortunately that returned an error... from the following line:

`return \'<a href="http://\'.  $matches[1] .\'">\'.  $matches[1] .\'</a>\';'`


`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN in /home/mydomain/public_html/project.php on line 112`

Comment: I read that a T_<something> error usually refers to the line above which would be `'$matches',` - any ideas?

Comment: There was a `'` missing before `return`. Sorry! I just tested it and it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Are your text stored as HTML or is it just a text containing URLs?

Comment: It is just text containing URLs and other text. Currently the table is 'varchar(1500)'.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Change the db feild to text,
2. While inserting data convert the html entities and escape the quotes.
3. while retrieving do the reverse process and  you can retrieve data in html format this way

Comment: This sounds sensible, but only some of the text will be urls. For example: `The website I am using in this text is http://www.google.com`