# converting em tags to links

Tags: php, preg-replace, php-5.3

The title is clear.

How can I convert this mini article

```
Test article here. This is a <em>test test</em> article.
This is the other <em>line</em>.
```

to that by php

```
Test article here. This is a <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/test test">test test</a> article.
This is the other <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/line">line</a>.
```

Comment: where does the value of `href` come from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139140/replace-non-html-links-with-a-tags?rq=1

Comment: it's the text from inside of the em tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$code = preg_replace('!<em>(.+?)</em>!', '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/\1">\1</a>', $code);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is in jquery just in case:

```
$("em").wrap("<a href='http://stackoverflow.com/"+$("em").html()+"'></a>");
$("em").contents().unwrap();
```